# what is the meaning of "Should we not be able to assist you at present"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "Should we not be able to" mean in the following sentence? does it have a positive meaning or a negative?

**Should we not be able to assist you at present, we will be keeping your information on file for future possibilities.**

Answer (score 1):

It's a flowery way of saying *if*. It basically means the same as:

> If we cannot assist you now, we will keep your information on file for future possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Should we not be able to assist you at present, we will be ......

You can use 'should' instead of 'if' to refer to a possible event or situation in the future.

So if you read the clause with "if" as follows, the sentence will come across:

If we are not able to assist you at present, we will be ......

You can also use if and should together to convey this sense as follows:

If we should not be able to assist you at present, we will be ....

However, the use of should in the forms of 'should + subject + verb' and 'if + subject + should + verb' is somewhat formal.